# Adding qTip2 tooltips to each node of a jsTree

Tags: jstree, thymeleaf, qtip2

I am creating a tree structure using thymeleaf in a [recursive](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Generate-recursive-tree-structure-td4027644.html) way to generate the html ul and li elements. Afterwards, I transform this list into a tree using jsTree. Until there, everything is fine. Afterwards, I want to add a tooltip with html content to each element of the tree. I am trying it with qTip2 but for some reason it is only showing an empty tooltip on the root nodes (platform.projectname and platform.projectname2) and nothing at all in the children.

[image]

Has anyone done this before? Any advice will be appreciated.

HTML/Thymeleaf container for the tree:

```
<div id="jstree_demo_div">
    <div th:fragment="submenu" th:remove="tag">
        <ul>
            <li th:each="node : ${nodelist}">
                <span th:text="${node.path}" class="treeelement">Town hall</span>
                <div class="tooltip">
                    Logging configuration:
                    <br/><br/>
                    <select>
                        <option value="trace">Trace</option>
                        <option value="debug">Debug</option>
                        <option value="info">Info</option>
                        <option value="warn">Warn</option>
                        <option value="error">Error</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div th:with="nodelist = ${node.children}" th:include="this::submenu" th:remove="tag"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// jsTree
$(function () {

    // 6 create an instance when the DOM is ready
    $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree();

    // 7 bind to events triggered on the tree
    $('#jstree_demo_div').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
        console.log(data.selected);
    });

    // 8 interact with the tree - either way is OK
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree(true).select_node('child_node_1');
        $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree('select_node', 'child_node_1');
        $.jstree.reference('#jstree_demo_div').select_node('child_node_1');
    });
});

// qTip2
$(function(){
    $('.treeelement').each(function(){
        $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: $(this).next('.tooltip')
            },
            show: 'click',
            hide: {
                fixed: true,
                delay: 2000
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work I guess, check this: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/qy3gkc2v/).

Try to:

1. move your `qtip` binding into `loaded` jsTree event to be sure it is loaded before you start binding qtip;
2. bind to `jstree-ancor` class the jsTree node has
3. you do not need to iterate with `each`

The reason for your tooltip having no text is that when building the tree jsTree rebuilds your `<li>` elements leaving out your `.tooltip` divs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Having to wait until the nodes are loaded would make a lot of sense. I tried by using the "onloaded.jstree" as you suggest but unfortunately got the same result, only root nodes ([this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452205/how-can-i-tell-if-jstree-has-fully-loaded) talks about that too). Should the nodes Cat x.x.x of your example show tooltips too?
I checked jsTree docu and saw... "**loaded.jstree**:triggered after the root node is loaded for the first time.", "**ready.jstree**:triggered after all nodes are finished loading." Got the same even with ready.

Comment: I guess `ready` is a better place to call qTip binding. I also added same to `after_open` event so the children (Cat.x.x.x) of the just opened node get tooltips too - child `<li>` elements do not exist in the DOM until the parent node is opened (better of course move adding tips into a separate function and call from jsTree events to avoid code duplication). I updated same Fiddle.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer since it actually solved (or provided a workaround) to my problem. I still think there should be a neater way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way which suits better my needs, [here is a JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rrx9xdmn/6/).

First I register the method `nodeSelected` to be executed when a node is selected, then I create and show the tooltip. This allows me to assign a specific ID to `<select>`.

```
$('#jstree_demo_div').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
    nodeSelected(data);
})
...

function nodeSelected(data){
    console.log(data.selected);

    // Using getElementById since JQuery does not work well with dots in identifiers
    $(document.getElementById(data.selected + '_anchor')).qtip({
        content: {
            text: 'Logging configuration:<br/><br/><select><option value="TRACE">Trace</option><option value="DEBUG">Debug</option><option value="INFO">Info</option></select></div>
        },
        show: 'click',
        hide: {
            fixed: true,
            delay: 1000
        }
     });
    $(document.getElementById(data.selected + '_anchor')).qtip("show");
}
```